# Is there a way to let the program remember which URL was open when the user closed the program?

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to let the program remember which URL was open when the user closed the program? For example if the user closes the application, the last URL gets added to the loadURL. The program is being used for users that only can interact with touchscreen and cant leave the specific site. I am using windows 10 and the newest version of electron.

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window.
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`
    }
  });

  // The loadURL that loads if you start up the application.
  mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com");

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on("closed", function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// The toggleFullScreen function stated in the createMainMenu function.
function toggleFullscreen() {
    if (mainWindow.isFullScreen()) {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    }
}

function createMainMenu() {
  const template = [
    {
      label: "Options",
      submenu: 
      [
        {
            label: "Quit",
            accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+Q",
            click() {
              app.quit();
          }
        },
        {
            label: 'Toggle full screen',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+F',
            click: () => {
            toggleFullscreen();
          }
        },
        {
            label: 'Toggle developer tools',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+I',
            click(item, focusedWindow){
              focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();
  createMainMenu();
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q.
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", function() {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage is an option (not the only one of course)

Comment: @malarres does this work with electron tho?

Comment: @Kurbey just try it 

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

First, each time the URL changes, use LocalStorage in the renderer process. It will work just like in a web app.

Second, each the URL changes, have it send a message back to the main process, and have it write that to a local file. [`getPath('appData')`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) can be used to get the OS-specific directory of where settings files can be written.